# Access denied when calling the AssumeRole operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a cloudformation template that creates a lambda funciton as well as a role for that lambda function. I try assuming the role in the lambda function but keep getting the error :

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied
```

Is there a step I'm missing? Not sure why I don't have permission to assume the role. I'm assuming I'm missing some sort of permission if the error I'm getting is access denied as opposed to some execution error.

Cloudformation Snippet :

```
  "LambdaRoleCustomResource": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Condition": "CreateWebACL",
      "DependsOn": "WAFWebACL",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": {
          "Fn::Join": ["-", [{
            "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
          }, "Custom-Resource"]]
        },
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
            },
            "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"]
          }]
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [{
          "PolicyName": "S3Access",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [{
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification"
              ],
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", {
                  "Ref": "AccessLogBucket"
                }]]
              }
            }]
          }
        }
```

Lambda Function Snippet:

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
        sts_credentials = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/portal-cloudfront-waf-Custom-Resource', RoleSessionName='custom-resource-cf-session')
        sts_credentials = sts_credentials['Credentials']
        cf = boto3.client('cloudformation', aws_access_key_id=sts_credentials['AccessKeyId'], aws_secret_access_key=sts_credentials['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token=sts_credentials['SessionToken'])
        stack_name = event['ResourceProperties']['StackName']
        cf_desc = cf.describe_stacks(StackName=stack_name)

        global waf
            sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
            sts_credentials = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/portal-cloudfront-waf-Custom-Resource', RoleSessionName='custom-resource-waf-session')
            sts_credentials = sts_credentials['Credentials']
            s3 = boto3.client('waf', aws_access_key_id=sts_credentials['AccessKeyId'], aws_secret_access_key=sts_credentials['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token=sts_credentials['SessionToken'])
            waf = boto3.client('waf')
```

Comment: Do I even need to assume role if it's being pass in during the creation of the lambda function?

Comment: You should configure the Lambda function with the relevant IAM role so that it does not need to explicitly assume it. Also, it looks like you were using the wrong credentials and have now resolved the original issue. If so, it's probably good to either delete the original post or provide your own answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Lambda function will automatically use the permissions associated with the Role attached to the function. There is no need to create credentials.

So, just use:

```
cf = boto3.client('cloudformation')
s3 = boto3.client('waf')
```